# How do I run two shell commands in one line in Vim?

Tags: vim

I want to `sort` and `uniq` some lines.
I did

```
:'<,'>! sort -f|!uniq
```

But it gives an error.
Is possible to run two commands on one line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the second `!`. It should be just:

```
:'<,'>! sort -f | uniq
```

From [`:help :!`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3A%21):

```
Any '!' in {cmd} is replaced with the previous
external command (see also 'cpoptions').  But not when
there is a backslash before the '!', then that
backslash is removed.  Example: ":!ls" followed by
":!echo ! \! \\!" executes "echo ls ! \!".

A '|' in {cmd} is passed to the shell, you cannot use
it to append a Vim command.  See :bar.
```

So `!uniq` will be the last command run, with `uniq` appended:

```
:!ls
:!echo !uniq
```

Outputs:

```
lsuniq

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```